# Vite exclude settings file from being bundled

Tags: reactjs, json, asynchronous, vite

I am using vite and I have created a settings.json file to store environment variables that should be changed when installing the script.

How can I keep the file from being minified/bundled in the production version such that I can change it and the updated file will be used next time the app is accessed (without having to build it again) ?

I have seen that I can move it to the public directory, and fetch it instead of importing, but I can't figure out how to use it since fetch is asynchronous, I can't use top-level await because of browser compatibility also.

This is how I am using it right now:

```
import settings from "/settings.json";

export const loginSettings= {
  names: {
    signUpSignIn: b2cSettings.signUpSignInPolicyName
  },
  authorities: {
    signUpSignIn: {
      authority: b2cSettings.signUpSignInAuthority
    }
  },
  authorityDomain: b2cSettings.authorityDomain
};
```

How can I change this code so that they can be edited in production without re-building ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar requirement and I used rollupOptions in build settings of vite.config.js as follows:-

```
export default defineConfig({
....
....
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: './index.html', //Entry point

        'settings': './src/settings.js',
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: assetInfo => {
          return assetInfo.name === 'settings'
            ? '[name].js'
            : 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js'
        }
      },
    },
  }
```

This will output setting.js at the root of the dist and rest others as usual in assets. Make sure, you are importing the settings.js file somewhere in your code else vite will output empty chunk.